# Comparing all elements from two hashes more efficiently

Tags: perl, hash

I have two hashes in perl that each consist of about 250,000 elements. I have to compare each element from both hashes with each other, and perform another operation on the elements that are equal to each other. I have the following code, which makes ~60 billion comparisons, so takes way too long to finish:

```
foreach $key1 (keys %large_hash_1)
    {
    foreach $key2 (keys %large_hash_2)
        {
        if($some_other_var{$key1} == $some_other_var{$key2}) # so actually I compare another hash variable, using the keys from %large_hash_1 and %large_hash_2
             {
             # I print some stuff here to an output file using the $key1 and $key2 variables
             }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this more rapidly?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that both the keys from hash one and hash two exist in the third one? Also, you only need to do half of the comparisons in general, because `a == b` and `b == a` are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed that they exist in the third one! And indeed, I would only have to do half of them, you're right! But that would still make it take too long unfortunately...

Comment: Can you do them in parallel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably. It looks like you can reformulate the problem as

> Find all pairs of keys `K1` and `K2` such that:
>
> - `$some_other_hash{K1} == $some_other_hash{K2}`
> - `K1` exists in `%hash1` and `K2` exists in `%hash2`

so let's try an approach where you find solutions to the first condition first and then see if they satisfy the second condition. Iterating through all pairs of keys is O(n<sup>2</sup>) but we already have a strategy for finding keys that map to the same hash value quickly: use another hash!

Let's build a "reverse hash" of `%some_other_hash` so that `$hash7{VAL}` produces a list of all keys in `%some_other_hash` such that `$some_other_hash{KEY} == VAL`:

```
push @{$hash7{ $some_other_hash{$_} }, $_ for keys %some_other_hash;
```

That was an O(n) operation. Next we need to find values that map to more than one key.

```
foreach my $v (keys %hash7) {
    @k = @{$hash7{$v}};
    next if @k < 2;
    ...
}
```

If you find such a value, check if some of the keys are in `%hash1` and if some are in `%hash2`.

```
foreach my $v (keys %hash7) {
    @k = @{$hash7{$v}};
    next if @k < 2;
    @k1 = grep { exists $hash1{$_} } @k;
    @k2 = grep { exists $hash2{$_} } @k;
    if (@k1 && @k2) {
        foreach my $k1 (@k1) {
            foreach my $k2 (@k2) {
                print "$k1 from %hash1 and $k2 from %hash2 ",
                      "have the same value $v in %some_other_hash\n";
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Worst case, where it is common to find values in `%some_other_hash` that are mapped by more than one key, this loop is O(mn). Depending on your data, this search could be significantly faster than iterating through all pairs of keys in `%hash1` and `%hash2`.